# MockK - verify failing with arguments not matching

Tags: mockk

I've noticed that sometimes `verify` fails with "... call to ... happened, but arguments are not matching"

Here is a sample test that shows verify failing:

```
class TestStuff {

    val stuff = "1"

    @RelaxedMockK
    lateinit var testService: TestService

    @RelaxedMockK
    lateinit var testInterface: TestInterface

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)

        every { testInterface.testStuff } returns stuff
    }

    @Test
    fun testStuffCalled() {
        testService.testStuff(testInterface.testStuff)

        verify { testService.testStuff(testInterface.testStuff) }
    }
}

interface TestInterface {
    val testStuff: String
}

class TestService {

    fun testStuff(stuff: String) {
    }
}
```

If I change the line with the verify call to the following 2 lines, then it works:

```
let testStuffCopy = testInterface.testStuff
verify { testService.testStuff(testStuffCopy) }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm unsure if this is a bug, but a quick workaround would be to use `stuff` as the verification, as you want the returned value to be it:

```
verify { testService.testStuff(stuff) }
```

This way you still test that the behaviour was called, and as you mocked the return of `testInterface` to return `stuff`, this should work.

[I created an Issue](https://github.com/oleksiyp/mockk/issues/32) in Mockk for this, and I'll update this answer when something is updated there.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm confused why that works and the other way doesn't since `testInterface.testStuff` should be returning `stuff`, so shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: It returns stuffw hen you call it. As you're trying to pass it as a parameter to an already mocked method, I believe it's not calling the stubbed behaviour when you're verifying

Comment: Then again, I'm unsure if this is actually a bug or just a countereffect

Comment: I freaked out with this. You've saved me from having to throw away the test, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In "verify", try to use "any()" instead of specific parameters to get rid of this issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).